# Android Cardview Fixed Size with Gridlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-cardview

I want to get a Fixed size Cardview containing an Image and some TextView. Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

tools:context=".ProductListFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Outlet : Head Office"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"/>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:hint="  Find Product"
        app:helperTextEnabled="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/search_icon"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search_icon" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        >

        <GridLayout
            android:paddingLeft="18dp"
            android:paddingRight="18dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:rowCount="2"

            >

            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                style="@style/CardView"
                android:id="@+id/sampleProductCard"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="6dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="80dp" //This is what i change from 80 dp to match parent
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/you_win"
                        />


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                        >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                            android:text="Apple Pie"
                            android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                            android:text="Rp. 40000"
                            android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:text="Stock : 4"
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            android:textSize="10sp"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>



                </LinearLayout>

            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                style="@style/CardView"
                android:id="@+id/sampleProductCard2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="6dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"

                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/you_win" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                        >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                            android:text="Apple Pie"
                            android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                            android:text="Rp. 40000"
                            android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:text="Stock : 4"
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            android:textSize="10sp"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        </GridLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>


</layout>
```

It'll produce the result: 
[image]

What i want is that the image has the same width as the CardView. But when i change the Image width to `match_parent`, it turn out to be:

[image]

Am i missing something ? If there is something more you want to know, just let me know.

Edit : I'm Trying to make each card would be like [this](https://www.codingdemos.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Android-CardView-Example-With-Gridlayout.png).

Comment: Dimas can you provide a screenshot of what exactly you want ??

Comment: why don't you use GridLayoutManager in  recyclerview??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try implementing-->

1.Add dependency in Gradle:

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

2.Change your code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

tools:context=".ProductListFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Outlet : Head Office"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"/>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:hint="  Find Product"
        app:helperTextEnabled="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/search_icon"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search_icon" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        >

        <GridLayout
            android:paddingLeft="18dp"
            android:paddingRight="18dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:rowCount="2"

            >

            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                style="@style/CardView"
                android:id="@+id/sampleProductCard"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="6dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                    />


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                        >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                            android:text="Apple Pie"
                            android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                            android:text="Rp. 40000"
                            android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:text="Stock : 4"
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            android:textSize="10sp"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>



                </LinearLayout>

            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                style="@style/CardView"
                android:id="@+id/sampleProductCard2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="6dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"

                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/you_win"
 android:scaleType="fitXY />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                        >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                            android:text="Apple Pie"
                            android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                            android:text="Rp. 40000"
                            android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:text="Stock : 4"
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            android:textSize="10sp"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        </GridLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: So i just need to add android:scaleType="fitXY" in the Imageview, right? Now it is working! Thank you very Much!!